# How do I extract First, Middle and Last Names?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr

Update: used the code on the actual dataset and we found suffixes (jr, sr, I, etc) are an issue. I have been scouring Stack and Google for solutions. Any idea on how to remove suffixes? I am thinking of removing the suffixes before using the regex code.

My sample data set looks like this.

[image: Screenshot of made up data points]

**Reproducible Sample Data**

```
dput(head(Sample_Dataset))
structure(list(MemberName = c("David owino", "Prisca omanya", 
"Geraldine nyambura bitange", "Ruiz aguila de espinoza", "Hera nyabute oganche", 
"Joney boka"), `Date of Birth` = structure(c(-235094400, 252806400, 
-641606400, 613180800, 697852800, 684115200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), `PCP Name` = c("Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742950", "Njeri, Lamech, Np :1677742951", 
"Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742952", "Agero, Larisse, Md :1677742953", 
"Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742954", "Denise, Lamech, Md :1677742955"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

```r
    #Splitting
    String <- stringr::str_split(Sample_Dataset$MemberName, "[ ]", n = 2)
    Last_Name <- sapply(String, '[', -1)
    First_Name <- sapply(String, '[', 1)
    Sample_d2 <-data.frame(First_Name, Last_Name)
```

The first part split it into first names and last names had 2 - 3 names (for individuals with 4 names)

```r
    names.split <- strsplit(unlist(Sample_d2$Last_Name), " ")
    Middle_Names <- sapply(names.split$Last_Name, function(x)
     if(length(String$Last_Name) == 2) {
        Middle_Names <- sapply(String, '[', 1)
  
      } else if (length(String$Last_Name) == 3){
        Middle_Names<- sapply(String, '[', 1:2)
      }

    )
    Sample_d2 <- data.frame(First_Name,Middle_Names, Last_Name)
```

I want to extract first name, last name and everything else be middle names.

Comment: Please share a reproducible sample of your data set with `dput(head(data))`, so that we can use it and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. I can update with some optional qualifiers for the last such as "de" later:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(name = c("John Tyler Smith", "Bryan Alexander", "Sarah Mary Thomas", "Tommy Hawk"))

extract(dat, 
        col = name, 
        into = c("first", "middle", "last"),
        regex = "^(\\w+)(?:\\s)?(\\w+)?\\s(\\w+$)", 
        remove = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   name              first middle  last     
#>   <chr>             <chr> <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 John Tyler Smith  John  "Tyler" Smith    
#> 2 Bryan Alexander   Bryan ""      Alexander
#> 3 Sarah Mary Thomas Sarah "Mary"  Thomas   
#> 4 Tommy Hawk        Tommy ""      Hawk
```

Comment: It worked but imputed NA for Ruiz who had 4 names

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you can go about extracting parts of names.
Just note that I create 3 capturing groups but made the the second one lazy as there might not be a match (no middle name):

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wHmvOg/1)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  extract(MemberName, into = c('First', 'Middle', 'Last'), 
          regex = '(^\\w+)(?:\\s([\\w ]+))?(?:\\s+)([\\w-]+$)') %>%
  mutate(across(c(First:Last), str_to_title))


# A tibble: 6 × 5
  First     Middle      Last     `Date of Birth`     `PCP Name`                    
  <chr>     <chr>       <chr>    <dttm>              <chr>                         
1 David     ""          Owino    1962-07-21 00:00:00 Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742950 
2 Prisca    ""          Omanya   1978-01-05 00:00:00 Njeri, Lamech, Np :1677742951 
3 Geraldine "Nyambura"  Bitange  1949-09-02 00:00:00 Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742952 
4 Ruiz      "Aguila De" Espinoza 1989-06-07 00:00:00 Agero, Larisse, Md :1677742953
5 Hera      "Nyabute"   Oganche  1992-02-12 00:00:00 Ogero, Lamech, Md :1677742954 
6 Joney     ""          Boka     1991-09-06 00:00:00 Denise, Lamech, Md :1677742955
```

Comment: Goodness, it worked!

Comment: I used the code on the actual dataset, and now middle names with upper case letters are imputed with NA. nothing shows up, not even their first name. Any ideas @Anoushiravan

Comment: Can you tell me how different are names in your real data and sample data? I assumed only first names here starts with capital letter.

Comment: I made some modifications to the regex so to make it more flexible when it comes to both upper case and lower case letters. Could you please check it and let me know how it works on your original data set?

Comment: The change worked! In the real dataset, all names start with a capital letter. All others have lowercase letters except a few. My goal was to separate the names and then change the first letter to upper case. I had trouble the past few weeks since I am new to R. Looks like regex is easier to implement, but I am lost with the terminology. Any resource you can recommend?

Comment: Oh that's nice then. Yes of course, it will give you a lot of flexibility and power for data manipulation. I started with this book in general, but for regular expression you can start from stringr chapter. There is no other reference better than this book for me to think of:
https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html 
Regex is common in all programming languages with some minor changes, so in case you have any question just search for a specific pattern's application on the google and you will get lots of answers. But first read that chapter.

Comment: Take your time and read it all also exercises are incredibly rich and exciting.

Comment: I also modified my answer to turn the names into title case.

Comment: Will do. Just noticed that names with hyphens are imputed with NA as well. Any ideas? So far, I have read to use [\w'-]+, but I am not heading anywhere. Where would I place it?

Comment: Can you give me an example of how those names look like? I think it is better to first replace all `-` with a white space and then use the code above. Just to ensure we have a consistent pattern.

Comment: For a name such as Prisca omanya-kunde, I would like it to be Prisca (first name) and omanya-kunde (last name). The code imputes NA for both names.

Comment: I just modified the answer. For this I modified the last capturing group as `([\\w-]+$)` so it matches any word character (alphanumeric and - ) one or any number of time while coming at the end of a string.

Comment: If this has solved your issue, please consider accepting this answer :)